# Find a big-O estimate for $f(n)=2f(\sqrt{n})+1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, asymptotics

Is the answer from the below linked question correct for my question?
Or does the differing of $+ \log(n)$ instead of $+1$ change the outcome of the master theorem?
[Similar question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170931/find-a-big-o-estimate-for-fn-2f-sqrtn-log-n?rq=1)

Comment: The answer may or may not be correct, but the _technique_ is identical - try a substitution $n=2^m$, solve the recurrence relation you get there, and then try and prove the result for $n$ not of that form.  (Note that you probably want to use $f(\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor)$ on your RHS, to cover the cases where $\sqrt{n}$ isn't an integer.)

Comment: You can also use my answer to my question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/979103/what-is-the-growth-of-tn-at-left-left-lfloor-sqrtkn-right-rfloor-right; just replace $b \log n$ with $b$ everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

As

$$
f\left(2^{\log_2 n}\right)= 2f\left(2^{\log_2 \sqrt{n}}\right)+1
$$

we can recast this recurrence as

$$
r(z)=2r\left(\frac z2\right)+1
$$

with $z=\log_2 n$ with solution

$$
r(z) = C_0 z-1
$$

and going backwards

$$
f(n) = C_0\log_2 n-1
$$

Answer (score 0):

Given Function:
f(n) = 2f(n^(1/2)) + 1

**Using the Master Theorem:**

We have a recurrence relation in the form of:

f(n) = af(n/b) + cn^d

**Where in our case:**

- a = 2 -> (coefficient in front of f(n^(1/2)))
- b = 1
- c = 1
- d = 0

**Now, we can apply the Master Theorem:**

- If a > b^d then f(n) = O(log(n))
- If a = b^d then f(n) = O(n^d (log(n)))
- If a < b^d then f(n) = O(n^d)

In our case, a = 2, b = 1, c = 1 and d = 0

2 > 1^0 -> 2 > 1

a > b^d

If a > b^d then f(n) = O(log(n))

Therefore, the big-O estimate for the given function is:

Answer: O(log(n))

Comment: How do you mean? This is not very clear...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).